# Show form in front of fullscreen application

Tags: c#, fullscreen, showdialog

Is there any solution for showing some form in front of fullscreen application fxp game? I mean something like Steam is doing while playing game and pressing Shift + Tab.

I'd like just to see some popup window in some coner which will notify me about something. And if I can access it somehow fxp for entering some text and clicking on something in it it would be great.

I'd best like to look for C# solutions. If there are any.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: this is not really easy, in fact you have to `Paint` your window on top of the game screen. You may have to use some hook.

Comment: I've found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12597/OSD-window-with-animation-effect-in-C It's working then using Windowed mode or playing movie in fullscreen. But if I run game in fullscreen it's not visible. Do you know some more details about that some article or some points in documentation which can help me. Or some keywords which can help me. Or I should just try to google about Painting?

Comment: it's pity that I don't have any experience in this field. You may want to search for `hook into DirectX`, `capture game screen`, the `game screen` is rendered differently, all the drawing stuff lie in a dedicated memory and we don't have any the so-called `Device context` (which is used frequently in Window GUI). BTW, I have to say again that it's not easy. You should try finding some `library` to help you hook into directX easily, you may have to read a lot. I also intend to research on this problem some day but it's not now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I know that it wouldn't be easy, but I'd like have some fun with it.